# Handle exception raised in except clause

Tags: python

In what I have written, `NoResultException` can be raised either in my `try` block or my `except UnexpectedAlertPresentException` block. I would like to go to the `except NoResultException` block in either case, but it only does this if `NoResultException` is raised in the `try` block. This is approximately what I have now:

```
try:
    # do things
except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
    # do other things, including possibly raise NoResultException
except NoResultException:
    # handle exception
```

I could change it to something like this:

```
try:
    # do things
except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
    try:
        # do other things, including possibly raise NoResultException
    except NoResultException:
        # handle exception
except NoResultException:
    # handle exception
```

to handle `NoResultException`, but I'm trying to avoid repeating myself. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Typically, you shouldn't be doing operations within an `except` block that could raise more exceptions, but if you have to, you could separate the handling into a separate function that handles the inner exception possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    try:
        # do things
    except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
        # do other things, including possibly raise NoResultException
except NoResultException:
    # handle exception
```

Try not to go overboard with the exception-handling control flow. The logic can get really hard to reason about, and the indentation can get really deep.